# SublimeText regexp replace quotes inside ruby tags

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to replace all occurances of double quotes, to single quotes, in ruby tags. Examples:

- `<%= t(".headline") %>`
- `<%= f.text_field :email, class: "center big" %>`

I've tried `(?<=<%=\s)(.*)(\")(.*)(?=\s%>)` which matches `t(".headline")` in groups like:

```
1.  [4-16]  `t(".headline`
2.  [16-17] `"`
3.  [17-18] `)`
```

Obviously it doesn't capture all occurances, and group everything else.

Also, I'm not what to replace with in Sublime's `Replace: [input box]`.
Something like `$1'$2` etc, but I won't know how many captures there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your regex doesn't work is obvious. It only captures one `"` and skips all the others but it should stop at each position where a `"` is located. It can be done with **[`\G` token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G)**.

Since Sublime Text Regular Expressions are Perl Compatible (PCRE) below regex is the right solution to this problem:

Regex:

```
<%(?:(?!%>)[^"])*\K"|(?!\A)\G(?:(?!%>)[^"\\])*(?:\\.(?:(?!%>)[^"\\])*)*\K"
```

Replacement string: `'`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN5xB4/1)

Explanation:

```
<%                      # Match beginning of Ruby tag
(?:(?!%>)[^"])*         # Match any thing except a double quote - caring not to jump over closing tag (zero or more times)
\K"                     # Up to a double quote (\K reset all match so far)
|                       # OR
(?!\A)\G                # Assert end of previous match
(?:(?!%>)[^"\\])*       # Match any thing except a double quote and backslash - caring not to jump over closing tag (zero or more times)
(?:                     # Start of non-capturing group (c)
    \\.                     # Match an escaped character
    (?:(?!%>)[^"\\])*       # Match any thing except a double quote and backslash - caring not to jump over closing tag (zero or more times)
)*                      # End of non-capturing group (c) (zero or more times)
\K"                     # Up to a double quote (\K reset all match so far)
```

Sublime Text preview:

[image]

Comment: I've actully never used `\K`. Learning something new :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use sublime, but in vscode something like this works:

`<%= t\("([^"]*)"\) %>` replace with `<%= t('$1') %>`

Still not perfect (presumes there's only one pair of ", if there's more you'll need to run replace again):

`<%=([^"]*)"([^"]*)"([^"]*)%>` => `<%=$1'$2'$3%>`

Comment: Updated example. I said all occurances of double quotes in ruby tags, not specifically in the `t()` method.